# Apache Spark (Python): check if coordinates from one DataFrame lie within coordinates of other DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, coordinates

I have two Spark DataFrames:

- **Area:** contains coordinates defining a square region

  - region_name
  - top_left_lat
  - top_left_lon
  - bottom_right_lat
  - bottom_right_lon
- **UserLocation:** contains location coordinates of a user

  - lat
  - lon
  - region_name (empty by default)

I'm looking for an efficient way to fill the *region_name* column for each UserLocation record with the region name in which the user is located (and null if user not in any region)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that none of the regions overlap?  Your questions use lat, lon but is this a 2-d setting or is it a globe?

Comment: Why can't just a simple Math like: `(user_lat>top_left_lat and user_lat<bottom_right_lat) and (user_lon>top_left_lon and user_lon<bottom_right_lon)`

Comment: @sedavidw as this is a (near) 2d setting, you can assume the regions do not overlap.

Comment: @DaanBakbanaan: Please provide sample inputs & output